# Code keeps looping and asking for input. How can I break?

Tags: python

New to python. After asking to input fruit and then number of in stock then the price how to add to the existing dictionary and break out of code?

```
stock = ()
prices = ()

stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}
prices = {"banana": 4, "apple": 2, "orange": 1.5, "pear": 3} 


for items in stock : 
    stock = {"banana": 6, "apple": 0, "orange": 32, "pear": 15}
    prices = {"banana": 4, "apple": 2, "orange": 1.5, "pear": 3} 
    stockname = input("Input stock name: ")
    stockquantity = int(input("Input number in stock: "))
    newitem = stock.update({stockname:stockquantity})
    print("The stock and quantity is :", stock)
    print("what is the price of the", stockname)
    addprice = float(input())
    newprice = prices.update({stockname:addprice})
    print("The stock and price is:", prices)
    if "cherry" in prices:
        break
```

Comment: You're resetting  `stock` and`prices` to the original value each time through the loop, so you're losing the updates.

Comment: Don'tuse `.update()` to update a single element. Just write `prices[stockname] = addprice`

Comment: Why are you looping through the items in stock? You never use `item` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to loop through the existing items if you're adding new items.

You shouldn't reassign `stock` and `prices` to the original value during the loop.

Use simple assignment to assign a single dictionary value. And `.update()` doesn't return anything, so there's no point in assigning the result of that to a variable.

To break out of the loop, check for an ending input before doing the rest.

```
while True:
    stockname = input("Input stock name (or 'done' to stop: ")
    if stockname == 'done':
        break
    stockquantity = int(input("Input number in stock: "))
    stock[stockname] = stockquantity
    print("The stock and quantity is :", stock)
    print("what is the price of the", stockname)
    addprice = float(input())
    prices[stockname] = addprice
    print("The stock and price is:", prices)
```